# Multiple slashes issue in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To remove multiple slashes from, i have used the code as :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Also the Mod Rewrite is on, but still not working as expected.

Is there anything i have missed?

Comment: Why do you have multiple slashes to begin with? It seems more like an issue to solve with PHP rather than Apache...

Comment: Basically i need to remove double slashes from anywhere after domain name

Comment: But why do you need to do this? It seems like a deeper problem, why is this happening would be my first question...

Comment: Hey, i m able to solve my issue, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need for a RewiteRule and a RewriteCond here, just one simple RewriteRule will do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will rewrite 2 or more / to just one (so it also rewrites /////// to / for example)